# NodeJS SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using NodeJS and Socket.io. This is my index.js

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
    var fs = require('fs');

    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");

    function handler(req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function( err, data ) {
        if( err ) {
          res.writeHead( 500 );
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead( 200 );
        res.end( data );
      });
    }
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>Impact Game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        #canvas {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="lib/impact/impact.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/game/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to localhost:3000, I get "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' main.js:1:0".

The tutorial I tried to follow was for ImpactJS + NodeJS + Socket.IO, to make a multiplayer game, but this is the furthest I've got with it so far.

Here is the content of main.js

```
ig.module(
    'game.main'
)
.requires(
    'impact.game',
    'impact.font'
)
.defines(function(){

MyGame = ig.Game.extend({

    // Load a font
    font: new ig.Font( 'media/04b03.font.png' ),


    init: function() {
        // Initialize your game here; bind keys etc.
    },

    update: function() {
        // Update all entities and backgroundMaps
        this.parent();

        // Add your own, additional update code here
    },

    draw: function() {
        // Draw all entities and backgroundMaps
        this.parent();


        // Add your own drawing code here
        var x = ig.system.width/2,
            y = ig.system.height/2;

        this.font.draw( 'It Works!', x, y, ig.Font.ALIGN.CENTER );
    }
});


// Start the Game with 60fps, a resolution of 320x240, scaled
// up by a factor of 2
ig.main( '#canvas', MyGame, 60, 320, 240, 2 );

});
```

Comment: What is the content of `main.js`?

Comment: You have a stray bracket somewhere...

Comment: If the error is in `main.js`, that's the file you should have posted.

Comment: Did you try and run main.js instead of index.js?

Comment: When I run index.html locally, it works, so that file should be good. But when I do it through Node, I get the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this:

> ```
> function handler(req, res) {
>   fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function( err, data ) {
> ```

No matter what the browser asks for, you are going to supply the content of `index.html`

So when the browser asks for `lib/impact/impact.js` or `lib/impact/main.js` … you give it the content of `index.html`.

You need to pay attention to what is being [requested](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) (`req.url`) and return the correct thing.

Comment: What I don't understand though, is that the tutorial I viewed had it like this and it was working completely fine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnQIkKHrdFY&list=PLma9Ymh3F3PkKpLotRXLPKUzIcN55ma6Z&index=6

Comment: I'm not going to plow through all that video to figure out what it failed to explain clearly enough. I'd imagine that it wasn't loading the index page from node.js at all and just left some boilerplate in.

Comment: I've downloaded the source from the video and tried it with the same result. The video is 4 years old though, so could this have worked back then but not anymore?

Comment: Using the same source code won't help if you point your browser at the wrong URL, which is what I imagine you are doing.

Comment: You are right. I was pointing the url to the :8080 instead of the actual folder where the files are located on wamp.